# Ubuntu 22.04 entering black screen randomly after suspend

Tags: dual-boot, gnome, gpu-driver

I'm using an Nvidia 3070 GPU on my Ubuntu 22.04, and recently it randomly entering to black screen after suspend. From my observable the Bluetooth devices are able to build connection, so it's just about the monitor output.

Here is my system info.

Results of `neofetch`:

[image: neofetch]

Results of `nvidia-smi`:

[image: nvidia-smi]